# How to configure hadoop mapper num per node(machine)

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I have a problem

My problem is I have a job(fetch crawler) that configurate **mapred.map.tasks** to 10,that means my job will create 10 mapper for once .but my cluster configurate **mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum** to 12

then all mapper will created in one single machine every time

How can I distribute all mapper to all machine homogeneous!

thanks very much

---

It is kind of like something mapper.per.node do ,but I hear some guy said that configuration was deleted.
1 when mapper.per.node was deleted?
2 How can i do now??

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be setting the mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum value to the number of cores present on the node of the TaskTracker. So assuming you have 4 cores on each of the nodes and the job spawns 10 map tasks, the max number of map tasks that can run on the TaskTracker will be 4.

Comment: I don't mean it,My point is ,just this job only have 10 mapper,May be there is other job will create mappers,, I mean ,,It is kind like mapper.per.node's business ,but i hear some guy said that configuration is be deleted.